# How Rasterstats function works

Tags: zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I would like to know how the `zonal_stats()` function from the library `rasterstats` works, as I am calculating the mean values of a raster within a polygon. If a raster cell touches partially the polygon boundaries, is the whole cell included in the statistics? or is it "clipped" and then calculated?
I cannot see a reference in rasterstats documentation.

Comment: What GIS or programming language is this? Python? This package? https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/rasterstats.html

Comment: Yes, and the parameter is all_touched. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the [docs that @Spacedman linked](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/rasterstats.html), via the `all_touched` parameter:

```
all_touched: bool, optional

Whether to include every raster cell touched by a geometry, or only those having a center point within the polygon. defaults to False
```

Comment: Thank you mikewatt, I haven't seen this parameter.